# what does "double a[size][size]" mean as a function argument?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I was coding a problem to print the elements on the diagonal and I do not understand why the first function is working and the second one is not.

Snippet 1:

```
void printDiag1(int size, double a[][101], int row, int col)
{
    if(size<=0) return;
    printDiag1(size-1,a,row,col);
    printf("%lf ",a[size-1][size-1]);
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
void printDiag2(int size, double a[size][size], int row, int col)
{
    if(size<=0) return;
    printDiag2(size-1,a,row,col);
    printf("%lf ",a[size-1][size-1]);
}
```

Can somebody explain me why and tell what

```
double a[size][size]
```

means in the arguments of the second function?

Comment: That's a 2D array, or array of arrays. However, whether it's valid code or not, need to be verified. Order of passing or function argument is not well-defined, IMO.

Comment: It's a variable length array, with its dimensions defined by the first argument. But of course, it's actually a pointer to the array, being a function argument.

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it compile? If so, does it run? Are there error or warning messages during compilation and/or runtime? Please [edit] and provide a [mcve] along with expected and actual output.

Comment: Aside: the functions recursively print the diagonal of the array, but it's unclear what the unused `row` and `col` are for.

Comment: The second function is not going to  work because you can't shape-shift a 2D array like that. In the first function the array keeps its row-length, but not in the second, so the indexing will go wrong.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use a recursive solution?  If not, I'd encourage you to code an ordinary loop, which will sidestep all the problems you're having, I believe.  Printing the diagonal of a matrix does not strike me as a problem that cries out for recursion.

Comment: Save time. `printf("%lf ",a[size-1][size-1]);` does not properly print the value of an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either function `a` is a 2D array (array of arrays). As per the rules of function parameters, arrays passed as parameters "decay" into a pointer to their first element. That's for example the very reason you are allowed to type `double a[][101]` with the left dimension empty.

So these two examples "decay" into pointers to arrays, `double (*a)[101]` and `double (*)[size]` respectively. The only difference is that `double (*a)[101]` can only point to an array of size `101` and `double (*)[size]` can only point to an array of size `size`. The latter is a pointer to a variable-length array (VLA) with flexible size.

VLA can be used for increased type safety which is what's happening here. `printDiag2(size-1,a,row,col);` doesn't work because `a` still expects to point at an array of type `double [size][size]`, so you can't pass that to a function suddenly expecting `double [size-1][size-1]`.

I would strongly recommend to stay away from recursion in general. It's a pox and some 99% of all use-cases where we spot it on SO are invalid. In this case a plain `for` loop would have been much faster, much more readable, less memory consuming and likely without bugs such as the one you got here.